# Move image from top or center vertically

Tags: html, css, image

I have a simple Under Construction Page and want to align my under construction image to the middle of the screen. Horizontally it is no problem but vertically I cant even position the image.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Under Construction</title>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<style type="text/css">
body {
background-color:#d7df29;
width: 100%;
height:  100%;

}
.img {

text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto
vertical-align: middle;
top:500;    

    }

#html5 {
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="img"><img src="1.jpg" alt="Under Construction"></div>
<div id="html5"><img src="images/img_html5_FR.png" height="120" width="120" alt="" />    </div>
<img src="images/fb2.png" style="position: fixed; top: 350px; left: 0px;"     title="Bierzyk na Facebook'u" alt="Bierzyk na Facebook'u">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the one in the img class, 1.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make your `.img` have a height of 100%, you can set the image to be a `background-image` of that div (or of the `body`) and then vertically align it that way.  This should work as your other elements on the page are positioned absolutely and fixed

Comment: as I am a bit confused at the moment a code example would be great

Comment: Sorry, just noticed your image div is 500px from the top, my answer won't work so i will delete it

Comment: It dont has to be 500px from top. The best would be middle position in all resolutions.

Comment: Image size is 701 width 468 height

Comment: ah then delete your `.img` div and then add this to your body style `background:url('1.jpg') center center no-repeat;`.  I quite like sowmya's solution though, with your image dimensions the margin would be `-234px 0 0 -350px`

Comment: ok did it but now it looks like this http://s7.directupload.net/file/d/3156/mcud5j8f_png.htm

Comment: you forgot to delete your div.img too

Comment: how do I maintain the background color? deleting the div image I got this now http://s7.directupload.net/file/d/3156/ln8dc9q3_png.htm very strange and confusing

Comment: actually it is not centering instead I have this http://s1.directupload.net/file/d/3156/ob8xn6qr_png.htm

Comment: well it centers horizontally but vertically it is not working

Comment: try adding html {width:100% height:100%}

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
.img {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;  
    left:50% ;
     background:red;
    margin:-64px 0 0 -64px;
    }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ixufos/1/edit)**

Comment: I tried exactly the same code, but in localhost it looks like this http://s7.directupload.net/file/d/3156/pygbqrtn_png.htm